# Popup window - how to exit and click another view on the main layout with one click

Tags: android, popupwindow, layout-inflater

I have a popup window in my Android application that does not follow the behavior I want.  I can create the popup window as an anchor from a view and it closes when I touch out of the popup area.  **But I am unable to perform any actions with this click that only closes the popup window.**

I would like be be able to dismiss the popup window and click another view with the **SAME click**.  Does anyone know how to achieve this??

The code for the popup window is below:

```
        //Get the instance of the LayoutInflater 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Page_Activity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));

        //Initialize popup window size and attributes
        popup_window = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 210, true);
        popup_window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popup_window.setTouchable(true);
        popup_window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        //Show popup window
        popup_window.showAsDropDown(anchor);
```

Comment: AFAIK this is as designed, and this is how a user would expect it to work like.. May be someone on SO would answer..

Comment: popup dialog that contain two button , one for yes and one for no will help you ? this what you need ?

Comment: it is a painting app with a canvas in the background. I have a popup window for the user to choose colors.  I would like to be able to choose a color from the popup window and touch the canvas and be able to draw. 

Right now the user chooses a color, has to tap the screen (to exit the popup window) and then is able to draw.